# Why does UIWebView keep detecting phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with detect phone numbers unchecked.  However, it keeps underlining the numbers in this text:

```
Version: 2.1 3.19.2009
```

The text isn't in an anchor or anything.  Is there a way to force the UIWebView to not detect phone numbers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with Interface Builder's UIWebView attributes palette; the "Detects Phone Numbers" checkbox does not seem to have any affect.  Examining the UIWebView's detectsPhoneNumbers property at runtime shows that it was not actually modified by IB.

For now, setting the detectsPhoneNumbers property in code to "NO" will work fine.  The problem is only with the IB palette.

Unless we're both missing something, this is a bug.  I'd suggest filing it at http://bugreport.apple.com/.  Additionally, you can post it at http://openradar.appspot.com/ if you'd like to make it visible to other developers.

Comment: Strange - this doesn't work [mywebview detectsPhoneNumbers:NO] but this does mywebview.detectsPhoneNumbers = NO.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :).  Note that When using bracket notation, you'll actually have to call [myWebView setDetectsPhoneNumbers:NO].  A property's accessor methods themselves take on standard getter and setter names.

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Comment: prefer webview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeNone; it does the same, thing, but it makes it clear what is happening.

Answer (score 7):

### Swift 3+ programmatically

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[webview setDetectsPhoneNumbers:NO];
```

It will work for you.....